# Display block content in current language

Tags: views, 8, blocks, i18n-l10n

I have multilingual Drupal 8 site.

I want to display views block in home page.

It should display block contents in current site language.

Example:

1. I have content type called "Book". Which has translated content in EN & NL.
2. Created views block for "Book" content type.
3. Placed this block in Home page.
4. Enabled language switcher block in Home page.

When I visit my home page `mysite.com` & `mysite.com/nl` above views block shows always English contents.

When I visit site in NL language, I want to display this block in NL language.

Comment: Just for clarification, you surely have seen, that on your view's edit screen under "Advanced" in the very right corner there's a language option? Which can be set to "current language"? Or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Added language condition in Filter Criteria to fix it.

[image]